# Unlock the user in PDB database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, pluggable-database

Everytime I turn on my computer and try to connect to `HR` database, an error pops up stating is blocked, then I go to SQLPLUS and log in as `SYSDBA`, and do the following script:

My question is, do I always have to do this? Is there any way to keep it always `UNLOCKED`?

```
1.- sqlplus / as sysdba

2.- show con_name;

3.- ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = orclpdb;

4.- COLUMN name FORMAT a20;

5.- SELECT name, open_mode from v$pdbs;

6.- ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE open;

7.- ALTER USER hr IDENTIFIED BY hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

8- conn hr/hr@orclpdb

9.- SHOW USER;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [Oracle 12c Post Installation Mandatory Steps](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/mandatory-steps-for-12c-installation/)

To open all/specific PDBs immediately after logon, create a **AFTER STARTUP** system level trigger in CDB.

Since, the PDBs are not open through a CDB start. Let’s see :

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
STARTUP;

SQL> SELECT name, open_mode FROM v$pdbs;

NAME                           OPEN_MODE
------------------------------ ----------
PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY
PDBP6                          MOUNTED
```

As you could see the PDB is still in mounted state and not open for read/write.

So, in order to have all the **PDBs automatically open**, do this :

Do, `SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA`, and then execute :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER open_pdbs 
  AFTER STARTUP ON DATABASE 
BEGIN 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL OPEN'; 
END open_pdbs;
/
```

It creates a after startup system level trigger in CDB.

Now unlock the user:

```
sqlplus SYS/password@PDBORCL AS SYSDBA

SQL> ALTER USER hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK IDENTIFIED BY hr;

sqlplus hr/hr@pdborcl

SQL> show user;
USER is "HR"
```

Now you need not open the PDBs manually, just connect to the PDB and the user you want to.

From **12.1.0.2** onward, you can preserve the PDB startup state through CDB restart:

```
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE pdb_name OPEN;
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE pdb_name SAVE STATE;
```

To discard the saved state:

```
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE pdb_name DISCARD STATE;
```

Comment: @thatjeffsmith The PDB save state option is available from **12.1.0.2** onward by applying the patchset. I've added more details to the answer, thanks!